# RegEx Match between beginning and ending problem

Tags: regex, vb.net, match

I want to match everything between "02A1" and "03" IF its 14 characters in between those two.

My RegEx Pattern looks like this:

```
(02A1)[0-9A-Z]{14}(03)
```

My problem: It also matches this:

```
02A103EEFFFFF702A103
```

What am i doing wrong? "EEFFFFF7" is clearly not between 02A1 und 03 as before the EEFFFFF7 theres a 03 and after it theres a 02A1.

Can someone help me?

Comment: It looks like it's working as expected. Do you want it to not match if those 14 characters contain `02A1` or `03`?

Comment: i basically only want to match everything that beginns with 02A1 and ends with 03 if its 14 characters long. So "02A103EEFFFFF702A103" shouldnt be a match as theres 02A103 - nothing between 02A1 and 03 -> no match, EEFFFFF7 -> no match, 02A103 again, no match as nothing between it

Comment: Your problem is that it's matching the entire string at once: (first part) `02A1`, (14 chars) `03EEFFFFF702A1`, (second part) `03`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fourteen alphanumeric chars cannot contain a `03` substring, use

```
02A1(?:(?!03)[0-9A-Z]){14}03
```

If it cannot contain `02A1` either, use

```
02A1(?:(?!03|02A1)[0-9A-Z]){14}03
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BG54TA/1).

*Details*:

- `02A1` - a `02A1` string
- `(?:(?!03|02A1)[0-9A-Z]){14}`  - fourteen occurrences of an uppercase ASCII letter or digit that does not start a `03` or `02A1` char sequence
- `03` - a `03` string.

Comment: second one did it, thanks!